# How can I insert text before an item with CSS?

Tags: css, xml

I'm sorry, I'm a complete newbie to CSS and I'm trying to create a custom display for an xml file with CSS.

My question is: how can I display a certain text before a certain element, e. g. "Project:" before each  element?

I tried like that with ":before" but that does not seem to do the trick

```
ThinkingRock
{
background-color: #ffffff;
width: 100%;
}

project
{
:before{content:"Projekt:";};
display: block;
margin-bottom: 30pt;
margin-left: 0;
}
description
{
color: #FF0000;
font-size: 20pt;
}
notes
{
color: #0000FF;
font-size: 20pt;
}
id, created, parent, topic, context, state, done, priority, modified, purpose, success, brainstorming, processed
{
display: block;
color: #000000;
margin-left: 20pt;
}
```

The xml file use is this one: http://www.trgtd.com.au/index.php?option=com_docman&task=doc_download&gid=16&Itemid=71
I've only added the first line `<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="thinkingrock.css"?>`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`:before` is a pseudo-selector itself, so it needs its own style block, like below:

```
project:before {
  content:"Projekt:";
}
project {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 30pt;
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wNEt3/

fiddle using your xml and css: http://jsfiddle.net/pRwMT/1/

Btw, http://htmldog.com/ is a great place to go for HTML & CSS tutorials, and they kindly point out W3schools inconsistencies, if you've visited there first :D

Comment: thanks! This only works if I do not use the last code block from my example which starts with "id, created, ...". As soon as I add those lines from my CSS file, the text is not displayed any more (Safari 5 on MacOS X).

Comment: Do you have a live link? I'll amend my fiddle to match yours more closely now that you've seen my solution works - give me a minute...

Comment: see the changed link with /2/ with the css code NOT working http://jsfiddle.net/wNEt3/2/

Comment: Hrm, I don't have OSX nor Safari, but Chrome16, Firefox9 and IE9 all show the "Projekt:" string before each project element. Can you check it in Firefox? http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html  lists the :before and :after pseudo-selectors as supported by Safari. Perhaps Safari doesn't like displaying the text because its displaying XML, but the text being added isn't even an XML text node?

Comment: now it works, thanks - I just don't see where my error was. Too many spaces in my css?!

Comment: Nah, you had ":before{content:"Projekt:";};" nested *inside* the existing style block for the project tag. The errors were: 1) bad nesting, fixed by making a 2nd style block just for the :before part 2) an extra semi-colon after the closing curly brace for that nested :before style block.

Comment: if you allow me one more question: Those projects can be nested, so one project can have several child-projects, which also have children. How can I display these sub-projects indented related to their parent-projects and how can I make them foldable (to hide a sub-tree by click) - maybe 2 keywords for a google search might be enough for me. :-)

Comment: indentation for all nested project tags (to the nth degree), add:  project project { margin-left:20pt; }. collapsible treeview-esque nodes depends on whether you want convenience as you develop, or you actually want an interface for you and others to continue using. I'll assume the latter as the former is solved by using a Text Editor with collapse functionality, though some browsers actually do this natively (IE)... google something like: "jquery collapse nodes", because you'll need javascript to do this. This is definitely worth a new stackoverflow question to give you some solid ideas.

Answer (score 1):

use `z-index` , `z-index` Only Work with `position:` `fixed,relative,absolute`:

```
project:before {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  position:absolute;
  content:"";
  z-index:-2;
}
project {
  position:relative;
  display: block;
  z-index:30;
}
```

or:

```
project:before {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  position:relative;
  content:"";
  z-index:-2;
}
project {
  display: block;
  z-index:30;
}
```

documention : https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp